# Deploying Ribbon Button Across all sites in a site collection

Tags: sharepoint-2010, sharepoint-designer, ribbon-button

I have created a custom ribbon button using SharePoint designer 2010 for a library in a site and have associated a workflow to it.
How to extend this functionality to all the sites in a site collection? 
If I create the custom ribbon button in the top most site of a site collection, can I have the functionality to be extended to all the sub-sites in that collection?
I am using SharePoint designer 2010 for the development, so is there a solution using SPD? I think using visual studio one can create a sandbox solution and apply that solution across all the sub-sites.
Are there any other tools to achieve this functionality?

Comment: I pretty sure that you cannot achieve this using SPD. You will need to use SiteCollection scope feature.

Comment: Is the SiteCollection feature has to be edited in Elements.xml file to achieve the required functionality?

Comment: No, you should have feature.xml file which contains Feature element with scope property.

Comment: Can you please provide me with further information to do that??

Comment: Generally you create feature using Visual Studio in which case you do not need to edit Feature.xml file manually. Just open feature designer and change scope. Or you creating feature manually? Then take a look at feature schema. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ms414322.aspx

Comment: Thank you for the inputs. I will try using visual studio to get it done.